# Github not loading all resources

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to pull this [webpage](https://xprmt.github.io/terminal/) to recreate my own startpage from 4chan's /wg/. The issue I'm having is that it isn't loading all the resources from the directory. Instead, [this](http://tenumbra.github.io/terminal/) is what it looks like. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Due to my low reputation, I can't add more links, but the direct repository is available from the links already provided. It seems as the the *.js files are not being uploaded. Any idea why github isn't allowing me to upload those files?

Comment: @MikeC Sorry yeah added the edit just now. Why isn't github allowing me to upload them? I tried through their application, through console, and their website directly. Is this a local issue?

Comment: If they aren't being uploaded to GitHub, that means you haven't committed them to the repository correctly. Make sure you understand how to add, commit, and push changes using git.

Comment: Why would they add some files but not others? This is using multiple different methods, but the *.js refuse to upload. git add ., upload files, etc

Comment: I couldn't tell you without seeing your setup. Remember: you need to do `git add path/to/file`. Also verify there's nothing in the `.gitignore` which would prevent you from adding them.